# What is more commonly used in US? "Cum Laude" or "With Honors"?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

I understand that the terms *Cum Laude* and *With Honors* are interchangeable, but which one is better understood in US and more commonly used?

Comment: Ngrams rarely tell the whole story, but they can be used as one piece of the puzzle.  [One Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=graduated+cum+laude%2C+graduated+with+honors&year_start=1920&year_end=2005&corpus=5&smoothing=4) suggests that _with honors_ might be more common. That data also seems to match my initial hunch.

Comment: Here's [another one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=magna+cum+laude%2Cgraduated+with+honors&year_start=1920&year_end=2005&corpus=5&smoothing=4) just to confuse the issue.

Comment: @Andrew: Excellent! That's why I avoid getting dogmatic over the results of an Ngram.

Comment: It often depends on whether the words on the degree are in English or Latin. I suspect that Latin is in decline.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Actually, *magna cum laude* means *with high honors*, so [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=magna+cum+laude%2Cwith+high+honors&year_start=1920&year_end=2005&corpus=5&smoothing=4) give a different picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both forms are well understood by people who care about such matters. You are free to use either.

Still, it is the diploma-granting institution (college or university) that decides whether to use English or Latin. My own baccalaureate was awarded "with highest distinction" — not *summa cum laude*. If you can find out what words were on the actual diploma, use those. If not, it doesn't much matter.

Comment: Does anyone every get an award _sine laude_?

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Hahaha. Many ought to be so marked, especially medical degrees. "Q. What do you call the guy who graduated from medical school at the bottom of his class? A. Doctor!"

Answer (score 2):

There are some differences in usage.  I have never heard a graduate degree being awarded With Honors. "Honors" is for me usually associated with a minimum grade point average (quantitative measure) and "[Summa] Cum Laude" being a discretionary, qualitative measure decided on a case-by-case basis, although it could be based on numbers as well.  In this I agree with [Dorian](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070816100400AAavq0R):

> Most master's programs do not have an honors degree. Since the minimum GPA for maintaining enrollment is a 3.0, there's not such a range of high and low grades, making high scorers the average instead of the exception. Everyone is expected to make good grades in grad school.